# virtualenv site-packages problem on OS X

Tags: macos, python, osx-lion, macports

I am using a MacPorts installation of Python2.7. I have used `pip` to install a number of packages in my home directory (`pip install --user`). The issue is that when I use virtualenv, none of those packages make it to the new virtual environment. I know it's probably because virtualenv doesn't look at the packages installed in my home dir when making the new environment.

I have been searching for a virtualenv option to make it see those packages as well, but no luck. Am I missing something or will I need to install the packages globally after all to make virtualenv see them?

Example:

```
pip freeze

> Django==1.3.1
> MySQL-python==1.2.3
> PIL==1.1.7
> virtualenv==1.6.4
> wsgiref==0.1.2

source workingEnv/bin/activate
pip freeze

> wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Comment: Which directory are you in and which pip is used?

Comment: I'm in ~/Desktop and the pip is the file that is installed with the MacPorts easy_install.

Comment: How do you make the virtual environment - as some parameters will not copy anything from site-packages. - Also for MySQL I find it easier to use macports to install that rather than easy_install

Comment: virtualenv workingEnv

however, those packages are installed in my home dir [~/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages], not in my main site-packages.

Answer (score 0):

virtualenv only copies from the global site-packages and not your local ones so I would either use macports to install all these needed packages or install them into the global install.
An alternative is to create a [bootstrap script](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/index.html#creating-your-own-bootstrap-scripts) that can add to PYTHONPATH to pick up these python packes in you home directory.